# Redirection www and non www to one server

Tags: nginx, server, digital-ocean

I would like to redirect my website after entering www.lombo.pl to only lombo.pl (with SSL certificate).

Now when something write www.lombo.pl it does not redirect. I tried to change my nginx file but still to no avail. The user can visit my website via www.lombo.pl (which at the same time shows an error because I do not have a SSL certificate configured for this domain).

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/app/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    #listen 80;

    # add here the ip address of your server
    # or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name lombo.pl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/lombo.pl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/lombo.pl/privkey.pem;

    server_name 157.245.228.127;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/app/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/app/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/static/;
    }

    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name lombo.pl;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.lombo.pl;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.lombo.pl;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You need a valid certificate otherwise the browser will not connect to the server. Nginx cannot help.

Comment: It looks like this was resolved. If the answer might help other readers, please write an answer.